# Sin poder transferir datos de PHP a mi BD SQL con el metodo PDO

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, pdo

Recurro aqui ya que tengo un problema de conexion de mi proyecto de php a mi BD SQL a travez de el metodo PDO, este nose que ocurre que finaliza exitosamente pero a mi base de datos no llega ningun dato. De antemano gracias por la atencion, bueno mi codigo el cual se le insertan los datos donde esta ubicado el formulario llamado Vista-Compras:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Compras</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="login-box">
      <img src="image/logo.png" class="avatar" alt="">
      <h1>"Compras"</h1>
      <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" class="form">
          <center>
        <label for="User">Bienvenido Usuario:</label>
          <br>
              <p>      
        <?php
              if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
        echo $_SESSION['usuario'];
         } ?>
            </p>

          </center>      
        <label for="producto">Producto:</label>
<select name="pt" id="pt">
   <option select  ed value="0"> Elige una opción </option>
       <optgroup label="Samsung"> 
       <option value="Producto1">Windows Vista</option> 
       <option value="Producto2">Windows 7</option> 
       <option value="Producto3">Windows XP</option> 
   </optgroup> 
   <optgroup label="Apple"> 
       <option value="10">Fedora</option> 
       <option value="11">Debian</option> 
       <option value="12">Suse</option> 
   </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Huawei"> 
       <option value="10">Fedora</option> 
       <option value="11">Debian</option> 
       <option value="12">Suse</option> 
   </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Xiaomi"> 
       <option value="10">Fedora</option> 
       <option value="11">Debian</option> 
       <option value="12">Suse</option> 
   </optgroup> 
</select>   
        <label for="Cantidad">Cantidad:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Cantidad del producto Comprar" name="ct" id="ct">  
        <label for="Domicilio">Domicilio:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Inserte su Domicilio" name="dm" id="dm">  
        <label for="Colonia">Colonia:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Inserte su Colonia" name="cn" id="cn">
        <label for="Ciudad">Ciudad:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Inserte su Ciudad"  name="cd" id="cd">
        <label for="Estado">Estado:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Inserte su Estado" name="ed" id="ed">  
        <label for="Pais">Pais:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Inserte su Pais" name="ps" id="ps">
        <label for="Pais">Correo:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Inserte tu E-mail" name="ccorreo" id="ccorreo">  
          <br><br>
            <?php if(!empty($error)): ?>
            <div class="mensaje">
                <?php echo $error; ?>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Finalizar Compra">
      </form>
    </div>
      <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

y el codigo el cual hace la conexion y rescata el valor de las variables que creo que de alguna parte de aqui se genera el problema llamado Compras.php

```
<?php session_start();

        if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
        }else{    
        header('location: Sesion.php');}


    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){        
        $pt = $_POST['pt'];
        $ct = $_POST['ct'];
        $dm = $_POST['dm'];
        $cn = $_POST['cn'];
        $cd = $_POST['cd'];
        $ed = $_POST['ed'];
        $ps = $_POST['ps'];
        $ccorreo = $_POST['ccorreo'];


        $error = '';

        if (empty($pt) or empty($ct) or empty($dm) or empty($cn) or empty($cd) or empty($ed) or empty($ps)){

            $error .= '<i>Favor de rellenar todos los campos</i>';
        }else{
            try{
                $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=login_tuto', 'root', '');
        }catch(PDOException $prueba_error){
            echo "Error: " . $prueba_error->getMessage();
        }

        }

        if ($error == ''){
            $statement = $conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO compras (id_compra, producto, cantidad, domicilio, colonia, ciudad, estado, pais,  correo) VALUES (null, :pt, :ct, :dm, :cn, :cd, :ed, :ps, :ccorreo');
            $statement->execute(array(

                ':pt' => $pt,
                ':ct' => $ct,
                ':dm' => $dm,
                ':cn' => $cn,
                ':cd' => $cd,
                ':ed' => $ed,
                ':ps' => $ps,
                ':ccorreo' => $ccorreo

            ));
           $error .= '<i style="color: green;">Compra registrada</i>';
        }
    }


    require 'frontend/Vista-Compras.php';

?>
```

:
y por ultimo la tabla de mi base de datos ubicada en el localhost:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

:)

Comment: Pero `Compras.php` no es el archivo al que mandas tus datos en el `action` de tu form, prueba sustituyendo lo que tienes ahorita por solo `action="Compras.php"`

Comment: Por otro lado veo que tu `id` es `AUTO_INCREMENT` entonces por que le mandas un valor? y en específico por que `NULL`?

Comment: Gracias por tus comentarios, respecto a lo de compras.php ya lo he intentado antes y hacia lo mismo, sin dar datos, y lo otro es que le pongo null para que lo omita y esa parte o hace la bd.

Comment: Bueno, pero tengo otro formulario que realiza un login y realiza el mismo metodo pdo que tambien tiene lo de null y funciona correctamente. Por ello no creo que ese sea el error.

Comment: lo que te menciono  es un punto de partida pues las llaves primarias el gestor las inserta por si solo, por eso te lo comento

Comment: además de eso a tu sentencia agregale un manejo de errores para que el PDO te muestre lo que esta fallando, aquí https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.errorinfo.php en la documentación oficial de PHP te muestra como hacerlo

Comment: oh ok, he seguido tu consejo y eh omitido ese campo pero aun sigue haciendo lo mismo

Comment: Desconocia de esta sentencia y donde me recomendarias insertar este? (Perdona mi ignorancia)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El valor de id_compra que envias en tu insert es null, entiendo que en algunos casos puedes enviarle un null a un autoincrement para que en automaticamente tome el valor que le corresponde, pero en tu caso id_compra es llave primaria por default esta restringido como no nulo entonces tienen una contradición, deberías probar no enviando el valor id_compra y en automatico el autoincrement le asignara el valor.

`$statement = $conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO compras (producto, cantidad, domicilio, colonia, ciudad, estado, pais,  correo) VALUES (:pt, :ct, :dm, :cn, :cd, :ed, :ps, :ccorreo');`

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que estás incluyendo en el INSERT el id_compra, ese campo no debe ir, ya que es clave primaria AUTOINCREMENTAL, y se genera sola cada vez que insertas registros en la tabla, debes sacarlo y creo que con eso se soluciona tu problema